# Finding characters per sec using asynchronous mode

Tags: asynchronous, bitrate, baud-rate, parity

> How many characters per sec(7bits+parity) can be transmitted over 2400bps line in asynchronous mode.

I calculated it to be 300 but the book says it is 240....how?

Comment: That all depends how wide the definition is a character is. IF only 7-bit it will be 300, but for 8-bit characters it will be less (probably 240).

Comment: That's clearly mentioned character is 7 bits here.@leppie

Comment: BUT how that's 240 for 8-bit???any formula???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous mode uses start and stop bits.
Start_bit + 7 Data_bits + Parity_bit + Stop_bit = 10 bits / character.
(2400 bits / second) / (10 bits / character) = 240 characters / second.